# How to combine two sql queries result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have designed the following two queries and i can join them with the left outer join to get the required results, but is there any way to just write one query to get the same results? How can i simplify it.

First Query brings total number of prople who have worked on the project and the second query is showing only those people who have worked on the project but belongs to different office.

**First Query**

```
SELECT  
VisitDate =  LEFT(Datename(month,v.VisitDate),3)
,COUNT( distinct i.InspectorID) AS TotalUsed

 FROM Visits v 
 INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp ON insp.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID 
 INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID  
 INNER JOIN Inspectors i ON i.InspectorID = insp.InspectorID 

 WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
 Group by Datename(month,v.VisitDate)
```

---

**Second query**

```
SELECT 
 VisitDate =  LEFT(Datename(month,v.VisitDate),3)
,COUNT( distinct i.InspectorID) AS TotalContractorUsed

 FROM Visits v 
 INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp ON insp.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID 
 INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID  
 INNER JOIN Inspectors i ON i.InspectorID = insp.InspectorID 

 WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
 **AND i.OfficeID  IN (5)**

Group by Datename(month,v.VisitDate)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the required final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in a single query:

```
SELECT  VisitDate = LEFT(Datename(month,v.VisitDate),3), 
        COUNT( distinct i.InspectorID) AS TotalUsed,
        COUNT(distinct case when i.OfficeID  IN (5) then i.InspectorID end) AS TotalContractorUsed
FROM Visits v 
 INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp ON insp.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID 
 INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID  
 INNER JOIN Inspectors i ON i.InspectorID = insp.InspectorID 
WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
Group by Datename(month,v.VisitDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not executed the query. Pls check.

```
;WITH CTE (VisitDate, TotalUsed) AS
(SELECT  
VisitDate =  LEFT(Datename(month,v.VisitDate),3)
,COUNT( distinct i.InspectorID) AS TotalUsed

 FROM Visits v 
 INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp ON insp.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID 
 INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID  
 INNER JOIN Inspectors i ON i.InspectorID = insp.InspectorID 
 WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)
 Group by Datename(month,v.VisitDate))

SELECT 
CTE.VisitDate
 ,CTE.TotalUsed
 ,ISNULL(COUNT(distinct i.InspectorID),0) AS TotalContractorUsed
FROM CTE 
LEFT JOIN  Visits v ON CTE.VisitDate = v.VisitDate
INNER JOIN InspectionScope insp ON insp.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID 
INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = insp.AssignmentID  
INNER JOIN Inspectors i ON i.InspectorID = insp.InspectorID 
WHERE a.ClientID IN (22,33)  AND i.OfficeID  IN (5)
Group by Datename(month,v.VisitDate)
```